# Запрос mysql на выборку

Tags: mysql, select

Здравствуйте!
Не могу понять, как реализовать и прошу помощи.

задание: "вывести клиентов, которые посетили 2 раза 2 страны". Т.е. в таблице заказ у меня указывается клиент и страна. И если он был 2 раза в Турции и 2 раза во Франции - выводим его.

Начал с этого -
`SELECT customer.fio, country.name, COUNT(country.name) FROM country, customer group by country.name`

выводит просто всех клиентов и все страны, будто каждый съездил в 10 стран

Comment: как связаны таблицы `country` и `customer`?

Comment: через таблицу zakaz

Answer (score 4):

ключевой момент — в использовании сочетания `group by` **и** `having`.

ниже в примере первый из `select`-ов использует созданный `view`, а второй из `select`-ов использует вложенный `select`.

функционально оба варианта аналогичны.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/650f5/1)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
create table klient (id int, name varchar(100));
create table strana (id int, name varchar(100));
create table poezdka (id int, klient int, strana int);

insert into klient values
  (1, "иванов"),
  (2, "петров"),
  (3, "сидоров"),
  (4, "зайцев");
insert into strana values (1, "земля"), (2, "небо");
insert into poezdka values
  (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 2), (4, 1, 2),
  (5, 2, 1), (6, 2, 1), (7, 2, 2), (8, 2, 2),
  (9, 3, 1), (10, 3, 1), (11, 4, 1);

create view kol as select klient, strana, count(*) as kol
  from poezdka
  where strana in (1, 2)
  group by klient, strana
  having kol = 2;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select klient, count(*) as posetil_stran
from kol
group by klient
having posetil_stran = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/650f5/1/0)**:

```
| klient | posetil_stran |
|--------|---------------|
|      1 |             2 |
|      2 |             2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select klient, count(*) as posetil_stran
from (
  select p.klient
  from poezdka p
  where p.strana in (1, 2)
  group by p.klient, p.strana
  having count(*) = 2
) as t
group by klient
having posetil_stran = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/650f5/1/1)**:

```
| klient | posetil_stran |
|--------|---------------|
|      1 |             2 |
|      2 |             2 |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT customer.fio, 
       country.name, 
       COUNT(country.name) AS total 
 FROM country 
 INNER JOIN customer ON customer.country_id=country.id 
 group by customer.id, country.name WHERE total=2;
```

По крайней мере так будет лучше

Comment: это выводит только тех, кто был в одной стране 2 раза, а как сделать в двух странах 2 раза ? Все равно спасибо)

Comment: боюсь, что в логике mysql это будет сделать тяжело.

Comment: может подскажите, как называется такая группировка или что-то(что гуглить) ??

Comment: Лучше попробуйте средствами языка программирования отфильтровать лишние записи. Возможно, вам поможет такая фишка в mysql, как `WITH ROLLUP` и что это такое на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/196692/)