# MySQL. Поиск по нескольким параметрам

Tags: mysql, поиск, join

Всем привет! Помогите, пожалуйста, составить запрос для поисковой формы.

Дано:

таблица autoservice (автосервисы)

```
id | name
```

таблица service (услуги которые предоставляют автосервисы)

```
id | name
```

таблица type (существующие типы автосервисов)

```
id | name
```

таблица autoservice_to_service (связка автосервисов с услугами)

```
id | autoservice_id | service_id
```

таблица autoservice_to_type (связка автосервисов с типами)

```
id | autoservice_id | type_id
```

---

Рассмотрим форму поиска по автосервисам в которой мы выбрали две услуги и два типа автосервиса. Нужно выбрать все автосервисы у которых есть ОБЕ услуги и которые относятся к ОБОИМ выбранным типам.

Если делать через in (service_id1, service_id2) то в выборку попадут автосервисы у которых есть хотя бы один из сервисов.

P.S. помимо autoservice_to_service и autoservice_to_type будет еще джоиниться несколько таблиц

Заранее спасибо за информацию!

Comment: Автосервис может принадлежать двум разным типам? Таблицы, которые джойнятся, идут 1-к-1? Т.е. если предположить, что для одного автосервиса без услуг в запросах всегда будет только одна запись (с услугами больше, т.к. автосервис предоставляет несколько услуг), то можно сделать выборку услуг через `JOIN`, сгруппировать ее по `autoservice_id`, и отфильтровать записи, у которых `COUNT(1)` будет меньше числа выбранных услуг.

Comment: вопрос уже задавался ранее, и на него уже [есть ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430835/178576).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Запрос mysql на выборку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/430795/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-mysql-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: one_dollar, я дополнил [свой ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/430835/178576) вложенным `select`-ом, без использования `view`.